# How do you ask in French: "Are you STILL sleeping?"

Tags: vocabulaire

I know that "Est-ce que tu dors?" is "Are you sleeping?" but how would you ask "Are you STILL sleeping?"

Comment: STILL = ENCORE : Je suis encore *en train de* dormir

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but that's probably what he/she means, @Amphiteóth , unless it's an issue of talking in their sleep or the narration of a dream sequence!

Comment: @Amphiteóth C'est une expression courante pour dire que l'on n'est pas encore bien réveillé, que l'on a ouvert un (seul) œil, mais que l'on est prêt à se rendormir, ou encore, que l'on semble réveillé, mais que l'on est dans un état comateux, "vaseux", que l'on n'est pas encore entièrement réveillé (entre rêve/somnolence et réveil)

Comment: Are you a native English  speaker? Your use of "I'm still sleeping" is weird here. As @PapaPoule says it's something you'd say while sleeping...  I'd say "I'm still asleep" (adjective) which in French would be *je suis encore endormie*.

Comment: Using you/tu instead of I/je would clear the ambiguity. I suggest you rephrase your question.

Answer (score 5):

Out of any context, a plain "est-ce que tu dors encore?" comes to mind.

Answer (score 4):

« Dors-tu encore ? » or you could say too « Es-tu toujours endormi ? » 
Encore and toujours meaning still.

Hmmmm... "Es-tu toujours endormi?" might be seen also as deprecatory. Meaning: "Are you always so asleep as not seeing anything?!?!? (or whatever was expected)?" In fact, in that case "Dors-tu encore?" is a more accurately translated by: Are you still asleep?

Answer (score 1):

So, I discussed this with my French girlfriend.

"Still" would be translated as "toujours" in this case - the implication is that it's been happening continuously. "Encore" is sort of like "again" - it would signify that the person stopped sleeping, woke up, then went back to sleep. So:

**Est-ce que tu dors TOUJOURS ?**

If this were said out loud (like an angry parent talking to their teenager), they would probably just say "tu dors TOUJOURS !?" or "tu es TOUJOURS endormi !?" ("you're STILL asleep!?"), using tone of voice to signify the question.

It's not necessary to be precise about the "am sleeping" part by using "...en train de...", unless you really want to stress the continuity of the action. But the difference here would be even more subtle than the toujours/encore difference.

Comment: No, here still is *encore*. *Je dors toujours* would be "I keep sleeping" or "I'm always asleep".

Comment: I disagree. For example, if somebody were to call and ask if you left the store, you might respond by saying "non, je suis toujours là."

Comment: The use of *toujours* in the example in your comment is not the same as in the sentence *je dors toujours*. In your sentence both, *encore* & *toujours* are acceptable and with the same meaning. *Je dors toujours* cannot mean you are still sleeping, but that you are **always** (meaning all the time) sleeping (maybe you've got a decease that makes you seep all the time...)

Comment: @KelseyRider Please note that I just edited the question to change it from the first person singular to the second person singular (to try to avoid the ambiguity that might exist in the first person), so you might want to either adjust your answer to the second person or else return the question to its original state if you prefer.

Comment: @PapaPoule Changing *je* to *tu* would change anything to this answer. *Tu dors toujours* would still mean "you keep sleeping" and not "you're still asleep".

Comment: @Laure I didn't mean to suggest that changing from "je" to "tu" would make Kelsey's answer any more or less correct, but simply that it would make it jive better with the 'tu' in the question. Anyway, how would one make the distinction between "STILL sleeping" & "sleeping AGAIN"? Couldn't the "repetition"/AGAIN sense of "encore" viv-a-vis its "persistance"/STILL sense cause some confusion? I know that REdormir would capture the AGAIN sense, but if one wanted to emphasize the AGAIN in/with an accusatory tone of voice, it seems that a separate adverb (?"encore"?) would be more effective, no?

Comment: @PapaPoule if we wanted to emphasise on the repetition of the action then we'd definitely use *en train de*. *Tu es encore* (or *à nouveau*) *en train de dormir*. And with an "accusatory tone of voice" (quoting you).

Comment: @Laure I think Larousse says that *toujours* **usually** means permanence or repetition, but that it can **also** be used to mean the continuation or persistence of a state from the past to the present: see for example, [*Je ne suis toujours pas satisfait.*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/toujours/78644)

Comment: I've checked this with a native French speaker - her first response was to use "toujours." In addition, "je dors toujours" is most certainly NOT "I keep sleeping." The verb "to keep" implies a certain persistence that would be better translated as something like "je continue à dormir."

Comment: @ChrisW Although I do not consider Larousse online a good reference what it says here is so vague that on the whole it is correct. It all depends on context and on the lexical meaning of the verb it is used with. Some verbs allow repetition, others don't. Same with continuation.

Comment: @KelseyRider I am a French native as well. And I maintain what I have written. Will write a complete answer with references (because we usually give references in answers on French Language) when I have time and if OP is more clear about they want. And *Continuer à* would be "keep on" and not just "keep".

Comment: Your explanation about *encore* is just not correct. Encore, according to context can mean repetition ([definition #2](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/encore)) or continuation ([definition #1](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/encore)). *Est-ce que tu dors encore* ? means "Are you **still** sleeping?"

Comment: @Laure My *Larousse junior poche* (printed on paper, and intended for primary school children) gives as its second meaning, "**(2) Encore, maintenant: *tu es toujours fâché contre moi?***" (which I think means, "Are you **still** angry with me?")

Comment: The fact that *toujours* and *encore* are interchangeable in some cases doesn't mean they're always interchangeable. As a native speaker, *est-ce que tu dors toujours* does not initially sound to me as "are you still sleeping". After a few repetitions, I can see how one could think so, but it still does not sound idiomatic at all to me. Asking someone in the morning if they're still sleeping, I'd definitely say *est-ce que tu dors encore*.

Comment: @Kareen Would they be interchangeable and have the same meaning in the following pair: "Tu es encore au lit?" & "Tu es toujours au lit?" I think the "problem" is that non-natives (myself included) are concerned about confusing the two meanings of "encore" (still and again) so we tend to go with "toujours" when we want to say "still" or "always" to avoid the ambiguity that we perceive when using/hearing "encore" in spite of it sounding unidiomatic (if we're lucky enough to recognize it as unidiomatic in the first place).

Comment: "Encore et toujours" are inbreed understanding of the French language. "Toujours" can mean again and again in a deprecatory way (in that context) or mean: continuing to; like in "encore". It is also in the way and context it is said. But if you are not sure, keep in mind that "toujours" is generally definitive and if not aware of its use in everyday life, can lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: I'll look it up. I agree that they can both be used, but "toujours" comes more quickly to my mind. I could think of a thousand times that I've heard it - "je suis toujours malade", "vous êtes toujours aussi charmante", "on est toujours au parc", etc...